# Adonis JS 5 Model Different Connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, adonis.js

I use AdonisJS v5 and I use multiple databases in my service. Can I set the connection on the model, without Database.manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. You have to define your connections in the database config file and then define the connection in the model

```js
public static connection = 'DB_USERS'
```